# Cannot query "object": Must be "User" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating sample-api which have posts and followers. Post should visible to followers only

My **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator_post_set', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    likes = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    comments = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower',null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers.py for the models:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        )
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)

class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'created_date',]

 class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = '__all__'
```

My **views.py**:

```
    class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
            serializer_class = PostListSerializer
            follow_model = FollowSerializer.Meta.model
            post_model = PostSerializer.Meta.model

            def get_queryset(self):
                try:
                    followers = self.follow_model.objects.get(follower_id = 
 self.request.user.id) 
                    queryset = self.post_model.objects.get(creator__in = followers)
                except self.follow_model.DoesNotExist:
                    queryset = None
                return queryset
```

When I call this view it returns the following error:

```
Cannot query "Follow object (1)": Must be "User" instance.
```

I need help Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you add the full traceback?

Comment: @JPG I updated the error traceback

Comment: this isn't the full version of traceback....pls add the whole traceback

Comment: I need the code for your serializers so I can replicate the problem

Comment: @HuLuViCa I included the serializers as well

Comment: Well, your code works for me, no error at all. I need you to share your `urls.py` and the whole traceback of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, `Post` model's `creator` is FKed to `User` model. So you need to query using `User` model instance, not `Follower` model.

You can use the following code:

```
following = self.request.user.following.all().values_list('follower', flat=True)  # because of related name
queryset = self.post_model.objects.filter(creator_id__in = list(following))
```

Here I have first retrieved the user ids using `self.request.following.all()` by reverse relationship. Then I have extracted the user ids using `values_list`. After that, I have used it in `Post.objects.filter(...)` method.

Comment: I used the above code it returns post  ```Post matching query does not exist.```

Comment: Maybe I queried with wrong values. Can you please try with `valurs_list('follower', flat=True)`?

Comment: thanks @ruddra  it works inspite of using get I am using filter(Post.bojects.filter())